# Writing sublists in a list of lists to separate text files

Tags: python, nested-lists

I’m really new to Python but find myself working on the travelling salesman problem with multiple drivers. Currently I handle the routes as a list of lists but I’m having trouble getting the results out in a suitable .txt format. Each sub-list represents the locations for a driver to visit, which corresponds to a separate list of lat/long tuples. Something like:

```
driver_routes = [[0,5,3,0],[0,1,4,2,0]]
lat_long =[(lat0,long0),(lat1,long1)...(latn,longn)]
```

What I would like is a separate .txt file (named “Driver(n)”) that lists the lat/long pairs for that driver to visit.

When I was just working with a single driver, the following code worked fine for me:

```
optimised_locs = open('Optimisedroute.txt', 'w')
for x in driver_routes:
    to_write = ','.join(map(str, lat_long[x]))
    optimised_locs.write(to_write)
    optimised_locs.write("\n")

optimised_locs.close()
```

So, I took the automated file naming code from Chris Gregg here ([Printing out elements of list into separate text files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673092/printing-out-elements-of-list-into-separate-text-files-in-python)) and tried to make an iterating loop for sublists:

```
num_drivers = 2
p = 0
while p < num_drivers:
    for x in driver_routes[p]:
        f = open("Driver"+str(p)+".txt","w")
        to_write = ','.join(map(str, lat_long[x]))
        print to_write   # for testing
        f.write(to_write)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    print "break"    # for testing
    p += 1
```

The output on my screen looks exactly how I would expect it to look and I generate .txt files with the correct name. However, I just get one tuple printed to each file, not the list that I expect. It’s probably very simple but I can't see why the while loop causes this issue. I would appreciate any suggestions and thank you in advance.

Comment: what is to_write printing 
list or tuple?

Comment: you need to indent your `f.close()` as right now you don't close any of your files except your last file (better to use the `with` statement within your loop).

Comment: to_write is printing the tuples one by one for each stop in the driver route. I have tried various indents on the f.close() and it doesn't change the output. The "break" is printing in the correct order so I assumed that the close was being executed at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the contents of the file `f` on every iteration of your `for` loop because you're re-opening it. You just need to modify your code as follows to open the file once per driver:

```
while p < num_drivers:
    f = open("Driver"+str(p)+".txt","w")
    for x in driver_routes[p]:
        to_write = ','.join(map(str, lat_long[x]))
        print to_write   # for testing
        f.write(to_write)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    p += 1
```

Note that opening `f` is moved to outside the `for` loop.